# Trying to create a custom layout

Tags: java, layout, jbutton, menubar, jgraph

Can anyone tell me how to do this custom layout in java? 
Tried adding the menubar in a north jpanel gridlayout and the button+graph in middle jpanel gridlayout, then added them to frame which has borderlayout, but none shows up. 
Thanks in advance

[image]

```
class {
JFrame frame ;

static JGraph jgraph ;

final mxGraph graph = new mxGraph() ;
JPanel jpanel = new JPanel() ;
...



public void GraphD() {


JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (2, 0));
                middlePanel.add(graphComponent);
```

frame.add (middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

```
public void imgbtn() {  




                 JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (2, 0));



                JButton imgbtn = new JButton("Export as Image") ;





                middlePanel.add(imgbtn);
frame.add (middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

public void Menu()  {

                    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (1, 0));

                    JMenuBar menuBar;
                    JMenu menu, submenu;
                    JMenuItem menuItem;

                    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                    menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
                    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                            "The only menu in this program that has menu items");
                    menuBar.add(menu);
                    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Option A",
                             KeyEvent.VK_T);
             menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
            KeyEvent.VK_1, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
           menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
            "This doesn't really do anything");
              menu.add(menuItem);
              menu.addSeparator();
              submenu = new JMenu("A submenu");
              submenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

              menuItem = new JMenuItem("An item in the submenu");
              menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                      KeyEvent.VK_2, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
              submenu.add(menuItem);

              menuItem = new JMenuItem("Another item");
              submenu.add(menuItem);
              menu.add(submenu);


              northPanel.add(menuBar);
              frame.add (northPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }


        public static void main(String[] args)
            {


                GUIquery frame = new GUIquery();
                frame.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(400, 320);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? And where are you stuck? A BorderLayout, holding a nested FlowLayout that holds a GridLayout using JPanel comes to mind.

Comment: I have tried BorderLayout in combination with gridlayout. I cant get the jmenubar added in the layout

Comment: `I cant get the jmenubar added in the layout` - You are not supposed to add a menubar to the layout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for the proper usage of a menu bar.

Comment: I have read it, but frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar); didnt work for me. It still didnt appear. So I tried adding jmenu to a jpanel as well but still didnt work.

Comment: `but frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar); didnt work for me` - obviously you are doing something wrong. Why would you reinvent the wheel by adding the menu to a panel? Use Swing the way it was designed to be used. All you need to do is download the example from the tutorial to prove to yourself that it works. Then you compare the code to see what is different. This is basic problem solving. The code you posted doesn't help because it is not complete. Anyway you should only be posting a `SSCCE` when you have a problem with a concept.

Answer (score 0):

forgot to add these 2 lines. Thanks

menuBar.add(menu);
         return menuBar;